# I am unable to make application release in monodroid

Tags: android, xamarin.android, web-reference

I have been using monodroid in debug mode, but now my app is finished testing and I would like to release it to a device and then to google play store, I get the following error

```
`Error  1   Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c4c4237547e4b6cd' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)   C:\...\SGEN com.Project`
```

I found this while googling the error [Xamarin Bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6429) but I don't really understand how to make it so my app can work. Can someone please help me?

Edit:
Apparently the Error is cause by using web references, the reported bug suggests to move the web references to a separate library that don't refer itself to mono references, any idea of how can I accomplish this?

Comment: This happens all the time to me in Eclipse when using Android Project Libraries. Granted in those cases its error 1 dalkvim jibberish that doesn't mean anything. Usually I can go change the library flags in eclipse to off, clean all the projects, then set the flags back to on and try exporting a signed release build again. Same issue as you though, works fine in debug and then blows up on release. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Tried cleaning the project, but it still fails at release. Anyway it wasn't even allowing debug on a device and now it is debbuging, but still can't release

Comment: It is a pain but you could try copying all of the code into a new project.

Comment: I really dont want to copy al the code, it's a pretty big project and it would take a lot of time

Comment: Already copied the code to a new project, anyway still not releasing, apparently it has something to do with the web reference I am using, any idea of what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem doing the following:

- Added a new project to my solution
- Added my web reference to this new project
- Deleted my web reference from my original project
- Added a reference to the new project on the original project
- Used new project web reference namespace to refer to my web reference

On this way, putting the web reference in a project that doesn't reference Mono.Android itself the application was able to release with no problems